# Can't start java DB Server

Tags: java, mysql, database, javadb

(I work in netBeans) When I go to Services, Databases, right click on java DB, start Server, and everything else are gray and when I click on them nothing happens. I also don't have mySQL in Databases. I tried to install jdk-14.0.2_windows -x64_bin.exe (I have an x64 bit laptop), and nothing happens, everything is the same. Does anyone know how to fix my problem?

Comment: So what database do you have that you are trying to start?

Comment: java DB in netBeans IDE .I want to install java DB in netBeans and use for my project.

Comment: The javadb product was discontinued years ago. Do you have the latest version of NetBeans? Javadb was essentially a rebranded version of Apache Derby which you can download from https://db.apache.org/derby/